# Undefined index: php in system_requirements()

Tags: 7, updating

Whenever updating modules on an existing Drupal 7 site, I got lots of these error messages

> Undefined index: php in system_requirements() (line 471 of xxxx/modules/system/system.install)

The code at that place reads

```
$files = system_rebuild_module_data();

...

foreach ($files as $module => $file) {
      // Ignore disabled modules and installation profiles.
      ...
      $php = $file->info['php'];
      if (version_compare($php, PHP_VERSION, '>')) {
        $requirements['php']['description'] .= $t('@name requires at least PHP @version.', array('@name' => $name, '@version' => $php));
        $requirements['php']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_ERROR;
      }
```

It looks as if `system_rebuild_module_data` reads module .info files from the database (and stores it in `drupal_static`).

The 'php' entry in module .info files is optional, and indeed missing in most of my contrib modules.

Is this a bug in system.install, or am I missing something ?

The odd thing is, lots of people should be having this problem, and I can't find much online. Perhaps there is something wrong with my installation ?

Comment: If 'php' entry is missing in modules .info files, then this message is valid as a notice. Meanwhile those messages shouldn't bother you. There is nothing wrong with your installation. You can however report an issue in the contrib modules queue to include proper 'php' version in their .info file.

Answer (score 1):

When a module does not set a value for `php` in its .info file, Drupal uses [`DRUPAL_MINIMUM_PHP`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/DRUPAL_MINIMUM_PHP/7.x) as default value. That default value is set by [`_system_rebuild_module_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/_system_rebuild_module_data/7.x) (which is called by `system_rebuild_module_data()`, which is called by `system_requirements()`).

```php
// Set defaults for module info.
$defaults = array(
  'dependencies' => array(),
  'description' => '',
  'package' => 'Other',
  'version' => NULL,
  'php' => DRUPAL_MINIMUM_PHP,
  'files' => array(),
  'bootstrap' => 0,
);

// omissis

// Merge in defaults and save.
$modules[$key]->info = $module->info + $defaults;
```

Since the data returned from `system_rebuild_module_data()` is only cached in memory, I suppose there must be a module implementing [`hook_system_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_system_info_alter/7.x) that removes the `php` index from that data.

`_system_rebuild_module_data()` invokes those hooks with the following code.

```php
// Invoke hook_system_info_alter() to give installed modules a chance to
// modify the data in the .info files if necessary.
$type = 'module';
drupal_alter('system_info', $modules[$key]->info, $modules[$key], $type);
```